# How can I count the number of properties in a structure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a function that returns one or more variables, but as it changes (depending on whether the function is successful or not), the following does NOT work:

```
[resultA, resultB, resultC, resultD, resultE, resultF] = func(somevars);
```

This will sometimes return an error, *varargout{2} not defined*, since only the first variable `resultA` is actually given a value when the function fails. Instead I put all the output in one variable:

```
output = func(somevars);
```

However, the variables are defined as properties of a struct, meaning I have to access them with `output.A`. This is not a problem in itself, but I need to count the number of properties to determine if I got the proper result.

I tried `length(output)`, `numel(output)` and `size(output)` to no avail, so if anyone has a clever way of doing this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
length(fieldnames(output))
```

There's probably a better way, but I can't think of it.

Comment: nah, that's probably the best.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Matthews answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880939/count-struct-properties-in-matlab/880960#880960) is the best for your problem:

```
nFields = numel(fieldnames(output));
```

There's one caveat which probably doesn't apply for your situation but may be interesting to know nonetheless: even if a structure field is empty, [FIELDNAMES](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fieldnames.html) will still return the name of that field. For example:

```
>> s.a = 5;
>> s.b = [1 2 3];
>> s.c = [];
>> fieldnames(s)

ans = 

    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
```

If you are interested in knowing the number of fields *that are not empty*, you could use either [STRUCTFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/structfun.html):

```
nFields = sum(~structfun(@isempty,s));
```

or a combination of [STRUCT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/struct2cell.html) and [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html):

```
nFields = sum(~cellfun('isempty',struct2cell(s)));
```

Both of the above return an answer of 2, whereas:

```
nFields = numel(fieldnames(s));
```

returns 3.